How to turn off URL auto-fill/complete in the search/address bar of chromium based browsers?
From the past 2-3 years, I have been facing a serious issue - the browsers have modified their address bars cum search bars to automatically fill up URLs from the browsing history. This is not only an inconvenience, but also an acute nuisance.
Let me show an example - in Google Chrome, if I want to open https://www.google.com, I will start by typing g in the address bar:

As can be seen above, the moment I entered g, the browser picked up a URL from from my search history and filled it in the address bar.
My Question is thus: How do I permanently disable this bad feature? (Please do not give a response like, clear your browsing history etc.) Since, Microsoft Edge is also Chromium based, I would like the method to turn this off for all Chromium based browsers.

I had a similar problem in Mozilla Firefox, but, Firefox provides the following flag configuration settings to control it:

